# video only plays sound?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html5-video

I am using the following video tag to render video

```
= video_tag(@file.path, controls: true)
```

The generated source code is

```
<video controls="controls" src="/system/videos/preview_video.mp4"></video>
```

In the browser the video only plays song. When i download it by clicking on down arrow then it downloads the whole video. But why is it only playing sound and not displaying video?

Am i missing a configuration in rails to allow video to play? I appreciate any help. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the mp4 file has a (video) codec your browser cannot play. Can you tell us, what codec is used, an what browser you are using? You can also try to set video type in the video tag: type=“video/mp4” (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)

Comment: ok i changed it to webm and it works in chrome. maybe it is because chrome doesnt support mp4?

Comment: According to w3school, Chrome supports mp4. But mp4 is just a container for streams (video and audio) and every stream can has a different codec. So the codec is relevant.

Comment: @TheBusinessTomcat how do i know which codec is used and is it possible to convert to a codec supported by all browsers?

Comment: @kofhearts ffmpeg can take you enough info about your file, it also can convert almost to any format. It is also easy to find a command for any codec you need on Internet